# Python os.fork()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to I create a process for each for item, and make the parent process wait for everything to finish?
I have this pseudo-code and want for create a fork for each requestImage(url)

```
page = requestPage(url)
additionalImages = parseHTML(page)
for urlImage in additionalImages:
    image = requestImage(url)
renderPage()
```

I know how to create a new process os.fork(), I'm just not sure how to make the parent process wait, something like  os.waitpid(  ,0)?

edit: Not sure if this works

```
children = []
page = requestPage(url)
additionalImages = parseHTML(page)
for urlImage in additionalImages:
     pid = os.fork()
     if pid == 0:
         children.append(pid)
         image = requestImage(url)
     else:
         pass
for child in children:
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
renderPage()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Did you try using `os.waitpid`? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

The `__doc__` for `os.waitpid` says:

> Wait for completion of a given child process.

So, yeah, that's what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have will not work as-is because you don't have a PID to pass into the second loop where you are checking waitpid.   If you use 0 for the PID there, you may be ok, because that will check for any child process to have finished.

What os are you on?  Linux and Windows have different behavior for waitpid.

Also, you may want to consider using subprocess.Popen instead of os.fork, I've found it easier to control, particularly if you need to communicate with the subprocess.

Comment: Im using linux.